# Can I apply for a PhD in the United States with a 3-year undergraduate degree from Italy?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, international

I'm currently studying in Italy for an undergraduate degree which is 3 years long (standard BSc in Computer Science). Since I'm also U.S. citizen, I was thinking it would be interesting to perhaps apply for a PhD in the states since it doesn't require a master's degree (it does in Italy). Is this possible or are the systems inherently different?

Comment: It usually depends on the university policy. Some universities require a master's degree whereas others set a cumulative GPA limit for applicants. You should check the university website.

Comment: Remember that a Bachelor's degree In the US is a four-year degree, with the Master's being at least an additional year (for students who want to have a life outside class and homework, anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many universities in the US have policies that prevent students with a 3 year bachelor's degree from applying for graduate admission.  To get into one of those programs you would have to complete at least one more year of study before being admitted to the graduate program.

Comment: Which is a good reason amongst others for the OP to look into MSc programs in the United States, then use those to get into a PhD.

Comment: Is a three year bachelor's degree "a thing" in the American college/university system?  I've never heard of it.

Comment: 3 year bachelors degrees are not at all standard in the US although there's been some discussion of moving to a 3 year bachelors degree to align with europe and to save money.  US Universities that won't accept 3 year bachelors typically won't admit a student to either an MS or PhD program with a 3 year bachelors.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I didn't quite get this before, but I now I think you're saying that the policy against 3 year bachelor degrees is designed to apply to European degrees, not American ones.

Comment: Actually, these kinds of policies were largely seen as being applicable to degrees from India.  The Bologna process has changed things so that the 3 year bachelors degree will be common and somewhat stronger.  I expect that many schools will adjust their expectations in response to this.

Comment: I doubt I can afford the 1 year master's program in the states (even if it's only 1 year). I guess I will simply opt for a 2 year master's program here in Europe which I assume would then be enough for a PhD in the states, right?

Comment: In my experience European students have typically completed a masters (or whatever their country called the "second cycle" degree) before coming to graduate school in the US.  Then again, I work at an institution that doesn't accept 3 year bachelors degrees for admission into the graduate program.

Comment: @LucaMatteis you could certainly apply to US PhD programs with your master's degree from europe, but even then, (1) you might be required to earn a master's degree first or (2) you might be required to take a substantial amount of coursework as part of the PhD.

Comment: This seems strange to me. I always assumed that the 3 yr bachelor's programs in UK or rest of Europe were equivalent to 4 yr US bachelor's due to A-levels in UK or similar studies in Europe. That is, yr 1 there is closer to yr 2 in US. (When studying in UK, I was a yr 3 in US but yr 2 in UK).